# Getting timestamp to date and time

Tags: python, sql, date, time, timestamp

I have a timestamp column in my db. I need to convert timestamp in to date and time respectively.

I use

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row1['timestamp']);
$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
$time = date('Gi.s', $timestamp);
```

When I use this code, I am not getting the time correctly.
INPUT: 2017-06-06 08:06:14
OUTPUT:
date: 06-06-2017
Time : 806.14

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$timestamp = strtotime( '2017-06-06 08:06:14');
$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
$time = date("H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo "$date $time";
?>
```

This will work..
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$timestamp='1496736374';                   //fetch timestamp value form DB.
$date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
dd($date);
```